# Elementary OS does not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

After installation the elementary OS did not boot.
I can't be sure what is wrong.
If I installed any other type of linux like LinuxMint or Fedora they seem
to support multiboot and are booting well.

It looks I might need check the installation media integrity also:
[![boot_error][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnn5Y.png

I reinstalled the ISO-image to the USB-stick and reinstall, but same issue remains that nothing appears in the boot in regards of the elementary OS.
I guess the FedoraLinux boot sector is 'deeper' there and it can not add the boot/grub configuration for the ElementaryOS.
Problem is the 'boot loader'. I can not see elementary OS in the boot loader selection menu, also I could not see the elementary OS in the BIOS boot selection.
I tried to make the installation on the existing Fedora linux partition, but it seems it can not delete maybe the Fedora linux boot files or something like that.

Comment: What do you see on the screen? If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 do you see a login prompt? What is your graphics card?

Comment: Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX250] driver: nvidia v: 470.74 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce MX250/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.74